# How to reconfigure Wireless Repeater?

Tags: router, wireless-router, wireless-extender

I have a cheap Wireless Repeater (model BE126, with a number 373544) to extend my wifi to upstairs. Technically it works just fine, but i'm unable to access its configuration, having initially set it up several months ago.

On the device, it lists a URL of `beconnected.client` and an IP of `192.168.66.253`. I have tried connecting to both of these (port 80) with no luck.

I identified the repeater's IP on the main wifi network (`192.168.14.2`), logged onto it and tried connecting to that IP, but that also didn't do anything.

When connected to the repeater, i checked the "default route", which was `192.168.14.1`. Connecting to that gave me the admin panel for the source wifi, not the repeater. On the off chance that that was also the repeater's administration IP, i disabled the source wifi and reconnected, and nothing loaded.

How can i access the configuration page for this repeater?

[image: Image of back of the device]

Comment: "_Manufactured by T&W_"... the RoHS label is likely a blatant lie, likewise for the CE mark. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_of_Hazardous_Substances_Directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to try a full network scan to see if i could find it. I'm on Ubuntu, so i ran `nmap` from the command line:

```
nmap -v --top-ports 10 192.168.0-255.1-254
```

Took a while, but it eventually came back with: `Nmap scan report for BE126 (192.168.14.44)`. I navigated to that IP (default port 80) and finally found the config.

I hope this helps other people, i Googled around for a while before solving it.